# Ruby puma-dev using wrong version of ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma, puma-dev

I've been debugging this for about a week now with no progress so I thought I'd take it to here. I've been doing research and staring at other StackOverflow solutions for this for hours and haven't made any progress. Currently running puma-dev on ruby 2.6.5. Whenever I run `puma-dev` this is the error message I get. (changing project names and some others for security reasons):

```
* Directory for apps: /Users/(myname)/.puma-dev
* Domains: test
* DNS Server port: 9253
* HTTP Server port: 9280
* HTTPS Server port: 9283
! Puma dev running...
! Booting app 'docugenerator-02fe76f7' on socket /Users/(myname)/.puma-dev/docugen/tmp/puma-dev-3410.sock
docugenerator-02fe76f7[3421]: sh: no job control in this shell
docugenerator-02fe76f7[3421]: Puma starting in single mode...
docugenerator-02fe76f7[3421]: * Version 4.3.8 (ruby 2.6.3-p62), codename: Mysterious Traveller
docugenerator-02fe76f7[3421]: * Min threads: 0, max threads: 5
docugenerator-02fe76f7[3421]: * Environment: development
docugenerator-02fe76f7[3421]: ! Unable to load application: Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch: Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.5
docugenerator-02fe76f7[3421]: /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.6.0/gems/bundler-2.1.4/lib/bundler/definition.rb:495:in `validate_ruby!': Your Ruby version is 2.6.3, but your Gemfile specified 2.6.5 (Bundler::RubyVersionMismatch)
```

Things I have tried so far are:

- Reinstalling puma-dev
- Restarting computer
- Changing `.env` and `.powenv`
- Changing `rbenv global` to 2.6.5

So far I've made no progress and I just get an error everytime I reload the page or restart the puma-dev server. Any tips or help is appreciated.

Comment: Try using rvm instead rbenv. I had some issues setting ruby versions for some gems and was solved when I switched to rvm.

Comment: can you specify ruby version in your gemfile to 2.6.3 and then bundle install again?

Comment: what is `ruby -v` in your current project dir? i think you should use it in your gemfile. otherwise i think you should specify ruby version in your Gemfile to 2.6.3 and run bundle install again

Comment: @CafeHey I may have an idea what the problem is, but first I need to know if you're using Bash or Zsh as your shell?

Answer (score 0):

It seems that the puma is running in wrong ruby version. rbenv determines which ruby version to use by several ways (see: https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#choosing-the-ruby-version ), and you need make sure the order of ruby versions that rbenv try to determines is correct. The most straightforward way is to create a `.ruby-version` in your project.

*.ruby-version*

```
2.6.5
```

Comment: Hey Sibevin. My project already has this and is set to the correct ruby version.

Comment: It's weird. I never use `puma-dev` before and I guess it may be related to the configuration of `puma-dev`. A possible solution is to set environment on `puma-dev` configuration to make sure it uses the right ruby version.